# Javascript Regular Expression Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In JavaScript sometimes we write Regular Expressions like:

1. ```
   var re = /ab+c/;
   ```
2. ```
   var re = /^ab+c$/;
   ```
3. ```
   var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
   ```

What is the difference between them? Which one is better?

Comment: Mostly, I will perform validations using Regular Expressions.

Comment: The first and thirds are the same... it looks for a string where `a` followed by 1 or more `b` then `c` any where in the given string like `abc` or `some abc` etc... 

where as the second one looks for a `a` followed by 1 or more `b` then `c` string like `abc` or `abbc` etc

Comment: 1 and 3 are slightly different, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760506/1967121).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options are different in some cases:

1. Find a expression abc or abbc or (a and one or more b and one c in all line).
   This teke the expression in all string:

   ```
   "abc", "abbbbbbbbc" yes
   "myabc", "myabbbbbbbbc" yes
   "abcismine", "abbbbbbbbcismine" yes
   "myabcismine", "myabbbbbbbbcismine" yes
   ```
2. Almos the same expression but find only explession.
   The ^ char delimits the begin of the line, and $ char delemits the end of the line.

This teke the expression in string:

```
    "abc", "abbbbbbbbc" yes
    "myabc", "myabbbbbbbbc" no
    "abcismine", "abbbbbbbbcismine" no
    "myabcismine", "myabbbbbbbbcismine" no
```

1. It is the same of the first

Comment: Thanks. Now i have some clarity. i think the second option restricts the format like: 'the string should begins with a and ends with c and contains 1 or more b's in between'.

Comment: Exactly, it's the idea

Answer (score 2):

You've got two different questions here.

**What does `^` mean at the start of a regexp and what does `$` mean at the end?**

These match the start and end of a string. `/a/` will match `"ba"` but `/^a/` won't, and both will match `"ba"`.

**What is the difference between `//` and `new RegExp()`?**

One is a literal, the other is created by converting a string.

In general, using a literal is simpler, faster, and clearer and is preferred. Using a string means you have to worry about escaping characters both for the regexp and the string containing it, but it also allows you to dynamically build regexps (e.g. from strings input by the user).

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /ab+c/;
```

will match `a`, then a sequence of `b`s, then a `c`, anywhere within a string.

```
var re = /^ab+c$/;
```

will match `a`, then a sequence of `b`s, then a `c`, but only if it's the entire string. `^` and `$` denote the start and the end of the string, respectively.

```
var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
```

is equivalent to the first regex.

```
var re = new RegExp("^ab+c$");
```

is also possible and equivalent to the second regex.

As for which one is better: The regex literal `/.../` is normally shorter and more readable, but there are some cases where the regex constructor `RegExp(...)` might be preferable:

- if you want to generate the regex on the fly, you can't use the literal syntax
- if you want to split the regex over several lines, the constructor syntax will let you
- the regex literal requires forward slashes to be escaped. A string literal needs escaping for backslashes and quote characters (only for those used to delimit the string). If your regex contains way more forward slashes than backslashes, `new RegExp(...)` might be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between 1 and 3, but 2 is a different regular expression completely. Number 2 is different, since the `^` matches the beginning of a line and the `$` marks the end of line. So while 1 and 3 would match the "abbc" in "_abbc1," the second one will only match "abbc" if it is on its own line (basically, it is sandwiched between newlines).

You are just using the literal syntax in 1 and using a constructor for 3. Unlike the difference for strings (where typeof returns something different for the literal "abc" than it does for `new String(abc)`), there is no real difference for using the literal for regular expressions, other than implementation details.

To get into the differnce between 1 and 3 a little deeper, you can check out the [MDN Javascript Guide > Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Basically, the literal is compiled, and you should use it when you know ahead of time what the pattern is (like in your example). You should use the object syntax when you construct the pattern dynamically at runtime (such as when it is based on user input):

> You construct a regular expression in one of two ways:
>
> Using a regular expression literal, as follows:
>
> ```
>    var re = /ab+c/;
> ```
>
> Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression when the script is evaluated. When the regular expression will remain constant, use this for better performance.
>
> Calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows:
>
> ```
>    var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
> ```
>
> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.